# Big O estimate of simple while loop

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Give a big-O estimate for the number of operations, where an operation is an addition or a multiplication, used in this segment of an algorithm (ignoring comparisons used to test the conditions in the while loop).

```
i := 1
t := 0
while i ≤ n
   t := t + i
   i := 2i
```

My attempt:

```
n = 1       i=2
n = 2       i=4
n = 3       i=8
n = 4       i=16
```

relationship of i to iteration is i = 2^n

How many iterations(n’) until `2^(n’) > n` (basically solving for n')

`n’ > log2(n)` thus the big O estimate is:

`O(log_2(n))` (read as log base 2 of n)

---

However, the book says it's `O(log(n))` - why isn't it base 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$O(\log_2(n))$ and $O(\ln{n})$ are the same thing, since $\log_2$ and $\ln$ are related by the formula

$$\log_2{n} = \frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{2}} \approx 1.44 \ln{n}$$

The multiplicative constant is irrelevant for the Big O notation.

---

More precisely, we have the relations

$$1.44 \ln{n} \le \log_2{n} \le 1.45 \ln{n}$$

Comment: Very elegant answer.